# How to search for data with a search bar in Next.js with Local API, using search query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I want to search for a product's title with a search bar. I am using a local API with Next.js. I want to search the products by title.

Url API Next

```dart
http://localhost:3000/api/products
```

JSON Data

```dart
{
    id: "1",
    title: "Polo manga corta",
    image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dj1ethf6d/image/upload/v1654948335/Mayoral/polo-manga-corta-contrastes-chico_id_22-06107-044-M-4_yfe04a.jpg",
    price: 12.9
}
```

Handler query

```dart
import { products } from './dataproducts'


export default async function handlerTitle (req, res){
    const products = req.query 
    const getTitle = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3000/api/products/${products}`
        );
        const data = await getTitle.json(products);
        res.status(200).json(data);
}
```

Search component

```dart
import { useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../../styles/SearchBar.module.css'

function SearchBar({ data }) {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

    const onChange = async (e) => {
        const {value} = e.target;
        setQuery(value)

        if (value.length > 3) {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/products?=${value}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(response)
        }
    }
```

input passing it the onChange and value

```
    return (
        <input 
        className={styles.input} 
        onChange={onChange}
        id='city'
        type="search" 
        name="search"
        value={query} 
        placeholder="Nombre producto..." />
    )
}

export default SearchBar
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I want to be shown the products that contain the title that I introduce in the searchBar, sorry if i don't understand english well! Thanks

Comment: You should try to pass the query param as `http://localhost:3000/api/products?title=${value}`, then in the API route retrieve the query param with `const { title } = req.query`.